# How to generate dynamic sub domain in laravel 5.2?

Tags: routes, laravel-5.1, wildcard-subdomain

In my site (school management system) , i want to generate mini-site for each of the teacher and the admin member. Where the teachers and the admin member can put there task and other things.By using sub domain, i want to get this mini-site. 
So, how can i get this sub domain and how to access that sub domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the documentation for sub-domain routing:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Don't forget to configure NGINX or Apache to properly handle sub-domains as well.
Good Luck !

Comment: @abdtpbd If you believe the answer helped you, don't forget to accept the solution :)

Comment: Do you have some resource on how to configure NGINX or Apache to properly handle sub-domains?

Comment: @Lama I'm more used to NGINX. I use wildcard for subdomain and send everything to Laravel (you can have an ideas there : https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-multi-tenancy )